# Run a GScript with the trigger-function

Tags: google-drive-api

I have to process several thousand files in Google and therefore have to work around the time limits. I have imagined that I start a search filter --->> edit the first e.g. 5 documents --->> thus ending the function. After 5 minutes the same filter should be started again --->> the next 5 documents are processed (thus hit list 6-10) --->> the function is terminated.

My search command could look like this, for example:

files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "2023-01-01"');

Hits over 10,000 files

Does anyone have an example script for me?

Greetings

I have no idea how I can solve this topic.

```js
function myTest() {
  var MyAccount = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var myCounter = 0;
  files = DriveApp.searchFiles('modifiedDate > "2023-01-01"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    myCounter++;
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

Comment: we are not a coding service can you show us what you have tried and describe your issues?

Comment: It was not my intention to abuse the forum for this - sorry. I have added my script to the question.